# Python and Parse HTML

Tags: python, curl

My input is the URL of a page. I wanna get the HTML of the page then parse it for a specific JSON response and grab a Product ID and another URL. On the next step, would like to append the Product ID to the URL found.

Any advice on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as retrieving the page, the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library is a great tool, and much more sanity-friendly than cURL.

I'm not sure based on your question, but if you're getting JSON back, just import the [native JSON library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) (`import json`) and use `json.loads(data)` to get a dictionary (or list) provided the response is valid JSON.

If you're parsing HTML, there are several good choices, including [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [lxml](http://lxml.de/). The former is easier to use but doesn't run as quickly or efficiently; the latter can be a bit obtuse but it's blazingly fast. Which is better depends on your app's requirements.

Comment: So yes, basically I will look at the page source, then search for a specific string. So I'm actually getting HTML back, not JSON. But within that HTML there is the string I need. Then I have to append that to another URL and likely do a driver.Get(URL).